# Autofac issues when resolving generic types implementing the same interface, need to Resolve() twice or more

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have an Autofac related issue with resolving generic types which implement the same interface, but have different type constraints. It could also be that my approach to implementing this particular use case (described further down) is plain wrong, in such case I would appreciate someone to correct my thinking.

See https://gist.github.com/sebekz/4c658a5c7551ba5a2b3fd81488ea3ee7 for a console app sample and read below for additional details.

What I have is two interfaces

```cs
public interface IMultitenant
public interface IMultitenantOptional
```

These interfaces are implemented by a bunch of classes, which are `IQueryable<T>` generic types of responses. So I could have requests which have response types of e.g. `IQueryable<Game>` or `IQueryable<Trophy>`, where both `Game` and `Trophy` implement one of two above mentioned multitenancy interfaces.

Now, I have two very similar class definitions

```cs
public class MultiTenantHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IResponseHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenant>

public class MultiTenantOptionalHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IResponseHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenantOptional>

public interface IResponseHandler<in TRequest, TResponse>
```

Instances of these classes are constructor-injected by Autofac in a separate class:

```cs
public class MediatorPipeline<TRequest, TResponse> : RequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    public MediatorPipeline(
        IResponseHandler<TRequest, TResponse>[] responseHandlers
    )
}
```

Autofac configuration goes like this:

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MultiTenantHandler<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance();   
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MultiTenantOptionalHandler<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance();
```

What I expected is that when the `MediatorPipeline` class intercepted a response with a return type of `IQueryable<IMultitenant>`, an instance of `MultiTenantHandler` class will be injected into the `responseHandlers` variable. Similarily, when the `MediatorPipeline` class intercepted a response with a return type of `IQueryable<IMultitenantOptional>`, an instance of `MultiTenantOptionalHandler` class will be injected into the `responseHandlers` variable.

These injected classes post-process my responses if they are of these two specific `IQueryable` sub-types.

It all builds and works. Kind of. It's all a part of a WebAPI project and the problem is, when I run my endpoint which is supposed to return `IQueryable<IMultitenant>` for the first and second time, I get:

> "message": "An exception was thrown while executing a resolve
>   operation. See the InnerException for details. --->
>   GenericArguments[1], 'System.Linq.IQueryable'1[Game]', on
>   'MultiTenantOptionalHandler'2[TRequest,TResponse]' violates the
>   constraint of type 'TResponse'. (See inner exception for details.)",
>           "type": "Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException",

First execution has this deeper in the stack trace:

> "stacktrace": "   at
>   System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition,
>   RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)\r\n   at
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Features.OpenGenerics.OpenGenericServiceBinder.TryBindServiceType(Service
>   service, IEnumerable`1 configuredOpenGenericServices, Type
>   openGenericImplementationType, Type& constructedImplementationType,
>   IEnumerable`1& constructedServices)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Features.OpenGenerics.OpenGenericRegistrationSource.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.GetInitializedServiceInfo(Service
>   service)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(Service
>   service)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__0(IComponentContext
>   c, IEnumerable`1 p)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)",

while the second execution has this in the same place:

> "stacktrace": "   at
>   System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition,
>   RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)\r\n   at
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Features.OpenGenerics.OpenGenericServiceBinder.TryBindServiceType(Service
>   service, IEnumerable`1 configuredOpenGenericServices, Type
>   openGenericImplementationType, Type& constructedImplementationType,
>   IEnumerable`1& constructedServices)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Features.OpenGenerics.OpenGenericRegistrationSource.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.GetInitializedServiceInfo(Service
>   service)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(Service
>   service)\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__16`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n 
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.GetInitializedServiceInfo(Service
>   service)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(Service
>   service)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__0(IComponentContext
>   c, IEnumerable`1 p)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)",

Third and all subsequent executions pass without any issues, returning expected payloads.

I would appreciate some help from Autofac experts.

**EDIT:**

I created a console program which illustrates the issue:

https://gist.github.com/sebekz/4c658a5c7551ba5a2b3fd81488ea3ee7

**EDIT 2:**

This ended up with a pull request into the Autofac repository which so far has been merged into develop with a potential for being included in one of the next Autofac releases. Please track the integration progress here https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/pull/796.

Comment: My first guess is that `.AsImplementedInterfaces()` is auto-discovering more than you expected, and finding a generic `IRequest<TResponse>` without constraints which gums up the entire container

Comment: At first I was not using `.AsImplementedInterfaces()` at all, I was using a more specific `.As(typeof(IResponseHandler<,>))`, but the result is the same. First call fails, second call succeeds. If it failed all along, I would get it - ok, wrong config, but it IS working after the first exception with no issues, resolving as the correct class instance. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the stacktrace the exception is caused in the `TryBindService` method from the `OpenGenericServiceBinder` class. This method tries to find a compatible service for the given type parameters. It calls the `IsCompatibleWithGenericParameterConstraints` method to ensure that the type parameters are compatible with the given type constraints, so I suspected that this method is wrong or at least not working as expected.

This suspicion proved to be correct, since the method returns `true` for all of the following calls:

```
typeof(MultiTenantHandler<,>).IsCompatibleWithGenericParameterConstraints(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<Game>), typeof(IQueryable<Game>) }); // expected: true
typeof(MultiTenantHandler<,>).IsCompatibleWithGenericParameterConstraints(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<Trophy>), typeof(IQueryable<Trophy>) }); // expected: false

typeof(MultiTenantOptionalHandler<,>).IsCompatibleWithGenericParameterConstraints(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<Game>), typeof(IQueryable<Game>) }); // expected: false
typeof(MultiTenantOptionalHandler<,>).IsCompatibleWithGenericParameterConstraints(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<Trophy>), typeof(IQueryable<Trophy>) }); // expected: true
```

So why does it return `true`? It uses the method `ParameterCompatibleWithTypeConstraint` to check whether the parameter is compatible with the given type constraint. At first this method checks if the constraint type is assignable from the parameter type, so:

```
typeof(IQueryable<IMultitenant>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IQueryable<Game>)); // true
typeof(IQueryable<IMultitenant>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IQueryable<Trophy>)); // false

typeof(IQueryable<IMultitenantOptional>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IQueryable<Game>)); // false
typeof(IQueryable<IMultitenantOptional>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IQueryable<Trophy>)); // true
```

So far it is working as expected. However, in case this check is `false` the `ParameterCompatibleWithTypeConstraint` does not return `false`. Instead it checks if it can create a generic type with the base type of the constraint (`IQueryable<T>`) and the generic argument of the parameter (`Game` or `Trophy`).

Since `IQueryable<T>` obviously does not define the `IMultitenant` or `IMultitenantOptional` type constraints this is always possible and the method returns `true`.

I am not sure why this second check is performed. It looks like a bug to me, but there may be a valid reason for this I am not seeing right now. I guess your best bet would be to create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac) to see what the Autofac developers are thinking about this.

#### The question remains why it is working the second time you try to resolve the service.

I have not confirmed it, but I suspect it may have to do with caching. Maybe Autofac remembers that using the `MultiTenantOptionalHandler` did not work to to resolve an `IResponseHandler<IRequest<IQueryable<Game>>, IQueryable<Game>>`, so it uses the only other possible registration, which is the correct one (`MultiTenantHandler`) by coincidence.

This assumption is backed by the fact that I have to resolve the `IResponseHandler<IRequest<IQueryable<Game>>, IQueryable<Game>>` **three** times to be successful in case I add another `IResponseHandler` implementation with yet another type constraints.

> It could also be that my approach to implementing this particular use case (described further down) is plain wrong, in such case I would appreciate someone to correct my thinking.

I don't know if your approach is best practice, but I don't see anything wrong about it and I guess it should work fine if the `ParameterCompatibleWithTypeConstraint` method would work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for this very through and down to the point analysis, this really got me into productive mode again. I guess deep down I suspected this to be an Autofac implementation issue, but never got to the point where this suspicion materialized itself strong enough for me to do a deep dive into Autofac repo code. Thanks for that, again.

Comment: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/794 issue logged with Autofac, I will update this answer when there is a resolution.

Comment: @SebastianZaklada I'm glad I could help :) I'm curious how the Autofac devs will respond.

Comment: I am just playing with the Autofac code to find out, why has this been implemented in the way that it's now and what would fix my problem. So far so good, if we remove the `Traverse.Across()` part of the `ParameterCompatibleWithTypeConstraint` function or extend the function itself so that it returned expected results for my use case this causes Autofac tests to fail. I am looking for a way to make these pass while still supporting my use case.

Comment: I posted an update to the Autofac issue #794 which is a starting point for a pull request which I am going to submit hopefully later this week. It solves my original problem and, what's most important, does not break any of the existing Autofac tests. I still need to test it more and figure out the best implementation, but so far it's looking good. If anyone is willing to comment or make the current solution better, feel free to contribute.